# Saving to a specific array list (java)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to do a project in which I save a list of students into their desired course. I know how to use an array list to save students into a list and call them again but I was wondering if its possible to save them to a specific array list. For example if its possible to do

```
n = //n gets its name (Comp 182 or Comp 101 from a file which is read)
//using java-util scanner to read a file which will have the course name there.

ArrayList<n> CourseList = new ArrayList<n>();
```

to create multiple lists in order to put them in the correct list or is there another way?

Comment: Is `n` a class? What is the structure of the rest of your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a Student class then you can save multiple records in a list. You need to define a list like

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

To add an instance to this list you need to make use of add method like

```
students.add(new Student(...));
```

In case if you try to add any other object to this list then you will have compile time error.